# onclick inside highslide expander

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, highslide

I'm changing highslide's expander. In expander I'm adding onclick event and it is not working. Here's my code:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onBeforeExpand = function (sender, e) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
var txt="<input type='text' name='id_kategorii' value='"+hs_id_kategorii+"' class='pole podpowiedz_kategorie_id' style='width:auto'>"
    +"<img class='hs_dodaj_do_kategorii' src='"+global_link+"style/nowy/ik/block--plus.png'>";
$(div).addClass('hs_admin');
$(div).html(txt);

sender.createOverlay({ 
    overlayId: div, 
    position: "top center", 
    hideOnMouseOut: false, 
    opacity: 0.8, 
});
$(".hs_admin img").click(function () {
    alert('k');
});
$( ".hs_admin .podpowiedz_kategorie_id" ).autocomplete({
    source: global_link+"ajax/autocomplete.php?rodzaj=kat",
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.value=ui.item.id;
        hs_id_kategorii=ui.item.id;
    }
});
$(".ui-autocomplete").css( "z-index", 1002);};
```

Autocomplete is working fine. Only click event is not working (no alert). I also tried

```
<img onclick='alert(\'k'\);'>
```

The same result.

Answer (score 0):

Alert isn't working but console.log works - sorry for bother...